# I need to primitive root of prime number?

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

I need to primitive root of prime number.I wrote this code but it has heap size error and it doesn't work for big number like 101.I don't have any other idea for calculating primitive root .If you have please help me .I need to it so much.Do you have any other algorithm for calculating primitive root of prime number?

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list1=new  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

private static int primitiveRoot(int prim){

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>  number=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();// this has all sequence numbers of x power of 0 to prime-1
        ArrayList<Integer> sublist=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int x=2;x<prim;x++ ){
            sublist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int power=0;power<prim-1;power++){
                int i=(int)((Math.pow(x, power))%prim);
                sublist.add(i);     
            }

            number.add(sublist);

        }

        for (int j=0;j<number.size();j++){
                for (int m=0;m<list1.size();m++){
                    if(number.get(j).equals(list1.get(m)) ){// element of number arraylist compare to list1,equality means that we find one of primitive root
                        a=j+2;
                         break;
                    }
                }

        }

        return a;// this is primitive root

    }
```

list1 is an arraylist of arraylists ,It contains all permutations of numbers between 1 to prime-1.It only work for small prime number like 7 or 11 .I increased heap size but It didn't effect.

Comment: I would try selecting more tags like `primitive`, `root`,`algorithm` etc.

Comment: I don't understand your program at all. `list1` is empty all the time and what is `a`?

Comment: List1 is arraylist of arraylists .I have a sublist [1,2,....,prim-1] and List1 contains all permutations of sublist.It not empty.a is primitive root of prime number.

Answer (score 0):

[Try wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) to find the algorithm.

In Java, the fast way to calculate `a^b mod n` is using `BigInteger` since it is secure and fast.

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("101");
BigInteger res = a.modPow(b, n);
```

Comment: speed of my program is low for calculating permutations not for calculate a^b mod n.I also saw Wikipedia already;)

Comment: FWIS, you iterate over list1, which contains 101! permutations. Do you think it is fast?

Comment: Yes i know it ,I know it isn't fast but this is only algorithm i could find.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;

public class PrimitiveRoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int p = in.nextInt();
        int m = p;
        if (isPrime(p)) {
            m = p - 1;
        }
        int primeRoot = 0;
        Map<Integer, Integer> primeFactor = getPrimeFactor(m);
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> map : primeFactor.entrySet()) {
            primeFactor.put(map.getKey(), m / map.getKey());
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
            boolean notPrimeRoot = false;
            Set<Integer> reminder = new HashSet<>();
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> map : primeFactor.entrySet()) {
                if(BigInteger.valueOf(i).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(map.getValue()), BigInteger.valueOf(p)).equals(BigInteger.ONE))
                    notPrimeRoot = true;
            }
            if (!notPrimeRoot) {
                primeRoot = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Prime Root is: " + primeRoot);
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int p) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(p); i++) {
            if (p % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Integer> getPrimeFactor(int p) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        while (p % 2 == 0) {
            insertToMap(2, map);
            p /= 2;
        }

        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(p); i += 2) {
            while (p % i == 0) {
                insertToMap(i, map);
                p /= i;
            }
        }

        if (p > 2)
            insertToMap(p, map);
        return map;
    }

    private static void insertToMap(int i, Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
        if (map.get(i) != null) {
            map.put(i, map.get(i) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is a python version for calculating ALL primitive roots of a given number :D

```
#David Isaac Pinos
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors

N=int(input("Insert number: "))
phi_N=N-1
factor_aux=prime_factors(phi_N)
print(factor_aux)
factor = []
i=0
while(i<len(factor_aux)-1):
    if (factor_aux[i]!=factor_aux[i+1]):
        factor.append(factor_aux[i])
    if (i==(len(factor_aux)-2)):
        factor.append(factor_aux[i+1]) 
    i=i+1
N_factor=len(factor)
print("")
print("")
i=2
a=0
while (i<10):
    print ("*****Evaluating for " , i , ":")
    j=0
    while (j<N_factor):
        tester=int(phi_N/factor[j])
        test= pow(int(i),tester)%int(N)
        print (i, "^" , tester, " mod ", N, "=" , test )
        if (test!=1):
            j=j+1
            if (j==N_factor and a==0):
                print ("********************* ",i, " IS THE PRIMITIVE ROOT OF ",N)
                primitive_root=i
                i=100
        else:
            j=N_factor
    i=i+1


print("All primitive numbers are: ")

i=1
while(i<N):
    print(primitive_root, "^", i, "mod",N,"=",pow(primitive_root,i)%N)
    i=i+1
```